# Does an insecure router bypass the privacy guarantee of a VPN connection?

Tags: security, networking, router, vpn, privacy

If I have a router that has a vulnerability that allows an attacker to gain full control it, does using a VPN on the network with the said router prevent an attacker from being able to snoop on the connection?

In other words, does using a VPN secure the connection from a device to a router on the same network? And would a VPS make a difference in this scenario?

Comment: Consider asking the question on Security or ServerFault stack exchange sites whichever is more relevant to your question. You may get better responses there, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

No, the whole point of a secure VPN is that the transport doesn't have to be trusted. Obviously a VPN that is not actually secure (is incorrectly implemented, has a design flaw) will not live up to the expectations of a secure VPN. But the whole point of a VPN is to not trust the transport.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the right place to ask this question but still, I'll answer here.

A VPN establishes a secure tunnel between two ends. What's in between does not matter as soon as the VPN was correctly established and the technology used is secured and "flawless".

The only exception (that comes to mind) is if one of the two ends is compromised. Examples:

- Your home network has a compromised router which advertises to your machine the wrong DNS hosts (`dns poisoning`). By doing so, you may end up establishing a VPN connection with a rogue machine (of some malicious guy). Note that this is very unlikely as some more conditions are needed to be successful in this attack, such as stealing or "faking" certificates or bypassing validation.

So, back to your question, using a VPN will fully secure the connection between the two ends (whatever exists in between), as far as you are establishing the connection with the right host/target.